# Changing isolation level within a Spring transaction

Tags: java, spring, oracle, isolation-level

I have a long section of code that I am executing inside a Spring transaction.  I now want just a small subset of that code to execute with a different isolation level.  If I call:

```
transactionTemplate.setIsolationLevel(Isolation.SERIALIZABLE.value());
```

Right before this small subset will this achieve my goal or must I set the isolation level and then create a new transaction?

Comment: I don't think you can change that on-the-fly in an open transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I know that in SQL*Plus, setting an isolation level implies starting a transaction:

```
-bash-4.1$ sqlplus mbobak/mbobak

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Dec 19 20:26:18 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select taddr from v$session where sid in(select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1);

TADDR
----------------


SQL> set transaction isolation level serializable;

Transaction set.

SQL> select taddr from v$session where sid in(select sid from v$mystat where rownum=1);

TADDR
----------------
0000007F510EFD60

SQL>
```

I assume the same would apply for your Spring API.

Just thought of something else.  Also, note that, in fact, the 'set transaction' must be the first statement in a transaction.  You cannot change the isolation level of a transaction, once it has begun.  Any attempt to do so, will result in:

```
ORA-01453: SET TRANSACTION must be first statement of transaction
```

Comment: I think the fact that you can only set the isolation level as the first statement means setIsolationLevel will not work on the fly as it would, otherwise, have to create a new transaction the boundaries of which would be unclear.